# Backing up OSX and bootcamp for a new drive

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, efi

I'm getting a new larger size SSD for my MBP and I want to transfer my existing OSX and bootcamp partitions onto it...

In preperation, iI've used bootable USB CloneZilla to clone everything onto an external drive that I have.

What I'm unsure about is how to restore it all back.. Once the new drive is fitted, if I then use clonezilla to restore the images (assuming that works), I take it that won't restore the partition tables (EFI) stuff that I'll need in order to dual boot.

How can I sort that out? I'm using rEFIt at the moment, do I just need to install that onto the new drive or are there additional steps I'll need to do?

Comment: See related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/93392/30551

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't clone it and put it back that way.
Feel free to try, but I'd never recommend it.

**Why, you ask?**

- You will always have more *useless waste* on your disk compared to a fresh install and  placing the items back you really need.
- You have partitioned it and it might cause trouble
- You're using an SSD, seeing you've bought a larger size SSD, I assume it was 128GB or 256GB max

**But cloning is easier!**

It might look easier indeed, but as stated - you have partitions and I don't see a right away guide using the exact same partitions you have. They might mess up, leaving you with copy everything one by one over and over.

Feel free to try it, but personally I wouldn't do it. Just my 2 cents..

Comment: My OSX install is quite clean, not that much on it. My windows partition is heavily customised and I really don't want to spend the X days rebuilding that. I suppose I could settle for a fresh OSX and a cloned windows, which would suggest I should use WinClone...

Answer (score 1):

Winclone 4 does an excellent job of backing up and restoring BootCamp partitions. I have used it with Windows XP (unsupported) and 7. OSX 10.7+

$29.99 is the price and I think it is well worth it.

http://twocanoes.com/winclone

Comment: It now seems to be $39.99